Trying to install MySQL and MariaDB on New MacBook Pro with homebrew
I am trying to install mariaDB to use as a dialect on datagrip for uni.
I have just bough a macBook and want to use datagrip on it.
I have been trying to install mariaDB but think I need to install mysql first, however after installing using homebrew I have had a few issues with solutions I've tried so far (I am using bash not zsh if this helps)
After brew install mysql, running mysql_secure_installation prompts for password but when I try and set one I get this error:
Error: Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/tmp/mysql.sock' (2)
After install, the other option is to mysql -u root but I get:
ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/tmp/mysql.sock' (2)
^^^ For reference 'ls -l /tmp/mysql.sock' says file doesn't exist so not sure if its not configured properly but this is after a fresh install so?
Running brew services list shows mysql stopped
Running brew services start mysql gives:
Bootstrap failed: 5: Input/output error With a failed to execute error
Not sure what else to try. Any suggestions

no, you do not need to install mysql first.  delete mysql and start over.

@ysth I have tried this, with Mariadb installed I get an issue when entering the root password, even though I am under the impression I haven't set one.

installing mysql, should you succeed, will make it harder to install mariadb, not easier.  and it is absolutely not going to help.  edit this question or open a new question to be just about the problems installing mariadb.
